# How to discard extjs session data

Tags: extjs5, extjs6

I am creating an Ext.data.Session in a view panel. Have models and association set.
how can i discard the session data. I did not find anything in the docs regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just destroy the Session object alltogether.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Session.html#method-destroy

The session (unlike the contained stores and associations) will not automatically persist its contained items and these will thus not be affected by the destroy.
If you keep references to the contained objects elsewhere (like in your view), these should survive the destroy operation.

Comment: I tried that, but it din't work for me. After calling session.destroy(), if i do session.getChanges(), i still see all session data. And i am not holding the reference of session or its objects anywhere else.

I still could not find a solution for this.

Comment: That's why the documentation says you SHOULD not access any of it's properties thereafter.
It's not like the Destroy method would immediately clean up the object, it simply marks it as available for cleanup to the Garbage Collector of your browser.
Depending on how much memory is available and what other stuff you do this can be cleaned up immediately or even minutes later.
More info on Memory Management and Garbage Collection in ExtJS:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/memory_management.html#core_concepts-_-memory_management_-_abstraction_and_garbage_collection

Comment: Sorry, the link is too long for SO. Check the Garbage Collection segment on that page.